# GAGA for moduli problems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces

In algebraic geometry moduli problems are described by a functor $F:\mathrm{Sch}^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set}$ and it is clear what a solution to a moduli problem is, namely a scheme X such that $F\simeq\mathrm{hom}(\_,X)$.

Suppose such a solution exists and happens to be a smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there anything GAGA can say about the analytification of $X$? I.e. does $X_\mathrm{an}$ still satisfy some universal property? More generally can I see if a complex manifold (or complex analytic space, or ...) $M$ is a solution to the moduli problem $F$ is some sense or another?

Comment: Have you considered the case of abelian varieties (as special cases of complex tori) or quartic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^2$ ?  In both cases the 'generic' deformation of the object is no longer algebraic.

Comment: In $\mathbb{P}^3$ I suppose? You're just talking about the family, not the fibres, right? So this is not an a priori reason why there can't be any relation between algebraic and analytic moduli, is it?

Comment: Oops, in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  In this case the analytic moduli is 20 dimensional and there are infinitely many 19 dimensional subspaces that are algebraic.  In fact for every g there is a 19 dimensional submanifold  corresponding to K-3 surfaces with a very ample linear system of dimension $g-1$ and degree $2g-2$ .  One can give a local description of the subspace, but I don't know if it globalizes.  In this case the algebraic subspace 'solves the moduli problem' that  ample line bundle deforms with the surface.  Maybe it's a matter of taste, but I wouldn't call that an analytic moduli problem.

Comment: Presumably your moduli problems involve geometric objects proper over the base and equipped with a fiberwise ample line bundle (equivalent to relative ampleness in both the scheme and analytic settings:  see section 3 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/amplepaper.pdf which has arguments that apply verbatim in the complex-analytic case). In such settings, Grothendieck proved analytifications of various algebraic moduli schemes are universal in the complex-analytic category (no parasitic smoothness hypotheses): see section 4.1 of the preceding link for references.

Comment: A more elegant viewpoint is to directly construct a universal analytic moduli space $M$ (e.g., using Douady spaces in place of an analytified Hilbert schemes), so for your algebraic moduli space $X$ one has a canonical map $X^{\rm{an}} \rightarrow M$ that is an isomorphism if and only if the answer to your question is "yes".  A map of complex-analytic spaces is an isomorphism if and only if it is bijective on points valued in any infinitesimal analytic space, and such points classify structures that are genuinely *proper*, so (with fiberwise algebraicity) GAGA applies to them and thus you win.